# Input text field with only bottom border

Tags: html, css, border, html-input

How do I style the text `input` field to make it only have a `border-bottom` like this one?

Expected Text `Input` Field

[image: SS]

Answer (score 60):

Use `outline:0` and then set `border-bottom`

```css
input {
  outline: 0;
  border-width: 0 0 2px;
  border-color: blue
}
input:focus {
  border-color: green;
  outline: 1px dotted #000
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Text" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 36):

Try this one

```css
.inp {
    border:none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #1890ff;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    outline: none;
 }

[placeholder]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    transition: text-indent 0.4s 0.4s ease; 
    text-indent: -100%;
    opacity: 1;
 }
```

```html
<input class="inp" placeholder="What needs to be done?"/>
```

Answer (score 14):

```
input {
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
#input_Id{
   border:0px;
   border-bottom:2px solid #eee;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
input {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #03a8f45e;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  color: #ccc;
        
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Enter search query" type="text" name="fname" autofocus />
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code to your css file. It will automatically change style of all the input boxes in your app.

```
input {
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #1890ff;
}
```

If you need to apply the style only for an input box then use the follwing class declaration,

```
.inputbox {
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #1890ff;
}

<input class="inputbox" placeholder="Enter a number"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.field {
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;
      border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray;
      border-radius: 0px;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?